# Allow chat messages in fixed width font to be marked as replies

Tags: feature-request, chat

Currently, fixed-font messages cannot also be "replies" in the chat--in the way that hovering over a message highlights what it replies to.

Beyond being kind of theoretically limiting, it's a problem for [RebolBot](https://stackapps.com/questions/3960/rebolbot-a-chat-bot-for-the-chat-rooms), who does runtime evaluations *(of any language that IdeOne supports, not just Rebol)*.  It would be nice if instead of repeating the code you asked to evaluate, if you could just hover over the evaluation and see the request that spawned it.

Maybe the easiest variant to support is if the first line contains only the reference number and a newline...if the rest of the message would be formatted as fixed:

```
 :13297046
     line one
     line two
     line three
```

Though maybe if the chat text has four (or maybe five?) spaces after the referenced message on the first line, it be considered a reply in fixed font.  e.g.

```
 :13297046    line one
     line two
     line three
```

I'm not sure about whether that should be four vs. five, the ambiguity of which may suggest only supporting the first form.

Comment: I think this feature could be nice, it's not just for bots too. My workaround so far has been to ping someone with a comment in the code but that's not as nice.